# How to erase a section using Jlink script

Tags: swd, segger-jlink

Currently i use:

*erase*

*loadfile "image.hex"*

**How can i erase only the section of the image?** 
the image size is known.

Comment: Yes, used in jlink script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SetFlashDLNoRMWThreshold 0xFFFFFFFF for read modify write and remove erase from script, this will result in changing only the section we upload an image to